# Match one column of a data.frame with all the columns in another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two data.frames:

```
 DF1   
 Col1      Col2      ......      ......   Col2000 
  A         H     
  c         d
  d         e  
  n         b   
  e         A    
  b         n    
  H         c    

 DF2    
  A
  b        
  c       
  d      
  e        
  n     
  H
```

I need simply to match the only one column in DF2 with each column in DF1. I need to match them because I need to know exactly the ranking of the match. Anyway I tried to write a function but since I'm not an R expert something goes wrong in my code:

```
  lapply(DF1, function(x) match(DF1[,i], DF2[,1]))
```

Comment: `sapply( DF1 , function(x) sum( x == DF2[,1] ) )`

Comment: @SimonO101 That doesn't return the ranking.

Comment: @JorisMeys at best the question is phrased unclearly. If it is what I *think* it is (i.e. column with most matches is ranked first) then wrapping the former in `rank()` should suffice.

Comment: @SimonO101 match() gives the ranking, he's just using function() wrong.

Comment: @JorisMeys ok, my understanding of ranking is differnt. I guess I approached it not realising the order of values in `DF2[,1]` represents the ranking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a correct result, you need a correct command :

```
lapply(DF1, function(x) match(x, DF2[,1]))
```

is doing what you're trying to do. Take :

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
  Col1 = c('A','c','d','n','e','b','H'),
  Col2 = c('H','d','e','b','A','n','c')
  )
DF2 <- data.frame(c('A','b','c','d','e','n','H'))
```

Then:

```
> lapply(DF1, function(x) match(x, DF2[,1]))  
$Col1
[1] 1 3 4 6 5 2 7

$Col2
[1] 7 4 5 2 1 6 3
```